# Using EXISTS instead of IN operator in delete-statement with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, exists, in-operator

As a SQL layman I was doing some data modification queries from Stanford's SQL course for practice. The last exercise was a bit tricky for me though I managed to get it done USING the IN Operator. As a little add-on I tried rewriting the query using EXISTS for the subquery. This proved harder than expected so now I wonder if there would have been a more elegant way for this.

It is about Q4: "Remove all ratings where the movie's year is before 1970 or after 2000, and the rating is fewer than 4 stars."

Exercises: https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-exercise-sql_movie_mod/?activate_block_id=i4x%3A%2F%2FDB%2FSQL%2Fsequential%2Fseq-exercise-sql_movie_mod

SQL fiddle can be found here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7f3ad

Thank you very much in advance!

I first tried dragging the additional AND statement into the subquery and merely replacing IN with EXISTS. Shortly after I found out that this would actually delete the entire table as the Exists-clause would then just evaluate to true without any reference to the outer table.

Having realized this I tried using an Alias in the outer table in order to be able to unambiguously reference the outer table from within. However, the system wouldn't let me do it. I believe they are running Postgres whereas we are using MySQL at Uni. Do you know whether MySQL allows aliasing in data modification statements?

Now for the query itself. It looks fairly verbose to me. Is there a smarter way to go about this using EXISTS? Or maybe something entirely different not relying on IN / Exists at all.

Using IN:

```
Delete 
FROM Rating
Where MId IN 
(
/*movies either before 1970 or after 2000*/
    Select r.MId
    FROM Movie as m
    INNER JOIN Rating as r
    on m.MId = r.MId 
    WHERE m.year <1970 Or m.year > 2000
) 
-- pick those with less than 4 stars
AND stars < 4;
```

Using Exists:

```
 Delete
 FROM Rating
 Where EXISTS(
     Select *
     FROM Movie as m
     INNER JOIN Rating as r
     on m.MId = r.MId 
     WHERE (m.year <1970 Or m.year > 2000) AND r.stars < 4
     AND Rating.rId = r.RId AND Rating.Mid = r.MId AND Rating.stars <4
);
```

One thing that had me struggling was the last bit where I check whether the stars in the outer table  are < 4. To me it looks like I am doing the entire query's work just inside the join condition. However, I found that leaving this out would actually delete all ratings with rId 201 as it finds the first 201 tuple complying with the criteria (outside the date range, less than 4 stars) and concludes that since this exists it could also delete the other tuple (in which the stars are actually >= 4)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not allow you to refer the table being updated or deleted, in such statements.  In your case, this is easily fixed.

I prefer `exists`:

```
delete r from rating r
where exists (select 1
                from Movie m
                where m.MId = r.MId and
                      (m.year < 1970 or m.year > 2000)
             ) and
-- pick those with less than 4 stars
     r.stars < 4;
```

You can do something similar with `in`:

```
delete r from rating r
where r.MId in (select m.MId
                from Movie m
                where m.year < 1970 or m.year > 2000
             ) and
-- pick those with less than 4 stars
     r.stars < 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative using `JOIN`

```
DELETE r FROM Rating r
INNER JOIN Movie m ON r.mID=m.mID 
WHERE r.stars<4 AND (m.year<1970 OR m.year>2000);
```